# django row based permission

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin

django's 1.3 docs say

> To enable object permissions in your own authentication backend you'll just have to allow passing an obj parameter to the permission methods and set the supports_object_permissions class attribute to True.

So I implemented my own authentication backend, set `supports_object_permissions = True` and defined a `def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None)`.

What I would *expect* now, is that navigating through the admin pages causes that method to be called mutltiple times (which does happen) and also, when I am on a model's listing site, the `obj` parameter to be filled with the actual objects. E.g. when I am listing products of a shop, for each of these products that method would get called so I can determine individually if that object shall be displayed and so on.

What *actually happens* though, is that `obj` is always `None`. Am I getting that concept wrong or do I have to anything else so that my actual objects get passed in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's default permission system is class level (table level), not row level. In other words, you cannot assign row based (instance based) permissions. This is a limitation on the system.

Projects like [django-guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) implement row-level (instance-level) permissions in django. You can find a listing of other [permissions projects](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/) at the djangopackages.com site.

Comment: I understand that django by default does not support this and you'd have to implement it yourself. That is what I am trying here and from the docs, as I understood them, the steps I mentioned above are what you'd need to do for all that. What would be the purpose of the obj param, if not for your own row-level permissions then?

Comment: What order did you list your backend? It should be after the default backend.

Comment: It's listed right after django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend